# ZeroMQ pub/sub with subscriber in PHP that cannot receive messages from publisher in C#

Tags: c#, zeromq

I'm using ZeroMQ to facilitate a publish/subscribe environment I'm needing. Both the pub and sub are running on the localhost.

**I implemented pub with C#:**

```
            var options = new Options();
            var parser = new CommandLineParser(new CommandLineParserSettings(Console.Error));
            if (!parser.ParseArguments(args, options))
                Environment.Exit(1);

            using (var ctx = ZmqContext.Create())
            {
                using (var socket = ctx.CreateSocket(SocketType.PUB))
                {                   
                    foreach (var endPoint in options.bindEndPoints)
                        socket.Bind(endPoint);

                    long msgCptr = 0;
                    int msgIndex = 0;
                    while (true)
                    {
                        if (msgCptr == long.MaxValue)
                            msgCptr = 0;
                        msgCptr++;
                        if (options.maxMessage >= 0)
                            if (msgCptr > options.maxMessage)
                                break;                        
                        if (msgIndex == options.altMessages.Count())
                            msgIndex = 0;
                        var msg = options.altMessages[msgIndex++].Replace("#nb#", msgCptr.ToString("d2"));                        
                        Thread.Sleep(options.delay);
                        Console.WriteLine("Publishing: " + msg);
                        socket.Send(msg, Encoding.UTF8);
                    }
                }
            }
```

**sub implemented in python:**

```
def main():

    test_connect = "tcp://127.0.0.1:5000"
    test_topic = ""

    connect_to = test_connect
    topics = test_topic

    ctx = zmq.Context()
    s = ctx.socket(zmq.SUB)
    s.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")
    s.connect(connect_to)

    print "Receiving messages on All Topics ..."

    while True:
        print "try to receive"
        objA = s.recv()
        print objA
```

I ran the sub first and then the pub. But the sub cannot receive any message from the pub. I don't know why.

I have tested with pub in python while sub in php and pub/sub in python. Both of them worked well. But when the pub or sub turned out to be implemented in C#, problems arose.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I have fixed the problem myself. Nothing wrong with the code. It is the version of ZMQ that is to blame. I referred clrzmq&libzmq(C#) in version 3.0 but php-zmq in version 2.2.0. So the communication failed.

Comment: If anyone got the same problem as me, please check the version of your ZMQ library. Though the ZMQ bingdings for different language are really in a mess.

Comment: :) a good practice to self.report() the version once launching the zmq.Context()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try simplifying your publisher, just for the sake of troubleshooting.  I modified the following from the first `PUB` example in the [ZMQ Guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all) found [here](http://zguide.zeromq.org/cs:wuserver):

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using ZeroMQ;

internal class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var context = ZmqContext.Create())
        {
            using (ZmqSocket publisher = context.CreateSocket(SocketType.PUB))
            {
                // your first potential issue lies here, if you're not
                // populating your addresses properly then you're not going to
                // bind appropriately
                // Test by hard coding the address
                publisher.Bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5000");

                int msgIndex = 0;

                while (true)
                {
                    // your second potential issue lies here, if your logic
                    // short circuits your send, that'll throw a wrench in the
                    // works
                    // Test by removing the logic and just sending a bunch of
                    // messages

                    var msg = "Message: " + msgIndex; // simplify
                    Console.WriteLine("Publishing: " + msg);
                    socket.Send(msg, Encoding.UTF8);
                    Thread.Sleep(500); // hard code
                    msgIndex++;
                    if (msgIndex > 1500) break; // hard code the break
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

... if that works, then it's a problem with your logic.  Just build out from there and see where the problem comes in.  If that fails, then there's likely a problem with your system set up or ZMQ library.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply, but the code you provide didn't work. I get the ZMQ library from this site http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/488207/ZeroMQ-via-Csharp-Introduction.

Comment: The problem is strange. The pub/sub can communicate when they are both written in C#. But a C# pub cannot send the message to a python sub and vice versa.

Comment: OK, that gets us somewhere... is all of this happening on the same computer? i.e. the c# pub *and* sub are on the same computer? the c# pub is on the same computer as the python sub? It's possible that it's just a general network communication problem, make sure at a minimum that you can ping one computer from the other.

Comment: @Jason - both PUB and SUB are said to be run against a localhost "loop-back" port //127.0.0.1:5000 ( hopefully on the same real-host )

Comment: Yeah, you already answered that in your original question, sorry about that, so there shouldn't be any network-dependent issue at play... have you tried python or PHP pub, c# sub?  doubt it'll be any different, but may as well rule out any functionality.

Comment: @user3666197 Thanks for your help. I have already solve the problem by myself. It is the version of the ZMQ for C# and php that caused the bug. I originally thought that a C# ZMQ(3.0) can work well with a php ZMQ(2.2), but it is really a stupid thought. I searched and tried different versions of ZMQ for C# and finally found the one that could match the version of php.

Comment: @Jason The pub and sub are running on the localhost, the same computer. Thanks for your help, I figured out that it was the ZMQ version mismatch between C# and PHP. I found the right version for C# that could communicate with the php version. Everything works well now.

Comment: glad you got it figured out, I erroneously made the assumption that both languages would be accessing the same library, but that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try the **SUB**-side in the following order of steps

```
ctx = zmq.Context()              // aGlobalCONTEXT
s = ctx.socket(zmq.SUB)          // aSocketOBJECT
s.connect(connect_to)            // aSocketOBJECT.connect() ...make PUB/SUB relation
s.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")  // aSocketOBJECT.setsockopt() SUB to everything from this PUB
```

Try the **PUB**-side to self-diagnose / print on CLI the result of each attempt to `.Bind()` ( print both the `endPoint` & return value ( confirmation code ) from the `socket.Bind()` call )

Comment: I have tried your every advice, but it seems there is still something wrong. Firstly, I toggled the 2 lines. Nothing different happened. Then I tried to print the return value of socket.Bind(), but it's a void function.

Comment: @sakonque what <endPoint> values do you provide to **PUB**-side process from the cmd-line?